# Convert groovy to kotlin dsl

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl, appdynamics

Hi everyone I use appDynamics library and the documentation only explains with groovy Gradle, I have a problem with converting the groovy Gradle script to kotlin Gradle DSL and I have tried several ways and several syntaxes and I even used converting tools from groovy to Kotlin Gradle also didn't solve the problem following script with groovy Gradle

```
adeum {
    
    account {
        name 'xxx'
        licenseKey 'yyyy'
    }
    proguardMappingFileUpload {
        failBuildOnUploadFailure true //should build fail if upload fails? Defaults to false.
        enabled true //enables automatic uploads. Defaults to true.
    }
}
```

[Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tet7q.png

and also i have to mention that the groovy is working fine

Comment: It's that your real license key and account name? Probably best not posting it on the internet if so

Comment: Not all Gradle Plugins work in Kotlin... some plugins may use Groovy features, making it almost impossible to use from other JVM languages. Unless you have complex Gradle files, just use the Groovy DSL if that works... spending time to get Kotlin working on a simple Gradle file may not be the best use of your time.

Comment: Do you have a simple example of a working groovy DSL build that we can look at to find the kotlin equivalent?

Comment: No, they are just random keys @tim_yates

Comment: you're right @Renato I solved it by writing Kotlin code that uses Closure to accept these plugins

Comment: Ah I didn't know you could create Groovy closures in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in some plugins in kts you have to use closure to determine the plugin packages

```
 adeum {
           account(closureOf<com.appdynamics.android.gradle.ADPluginExtension.Account> {
            this.name ="xxx"
            this.licenseKey ="yyy"
    
        })
        proguardMappingFileUpload(closureOf<com.appdynamics.android.gradle.ADPluginExtension.ProguardConfig> {
            this.failBuildOnUploadFailure = true
            this.enabled = true
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change `adeum` to `configure<ADPluginExtension>`, like this:

```kotlin
configure<ADPluginExtension> {
           account(closureOf<com.appdynamics.android.gradle.ADPluginExtension.Account> {
            this.name ="xxx"
            this.licenseKey ="yyy"
    
        })
        proguardMappingFileUpload(closureOf<com.appdynamics.android.gradle.ADPluginExtension.ProguardConfig> {
            this.failBuildOnUploadFailure = true
            this.enabled = true
        })
    }
```

I had some issues, when used `adeum` plugin with `kotlin-dsl`, where gradle sync not generated extensions accessors to `android`, `dependencies`, `implementation`, etc... provided from kotlin-dsl plugin.